# Php cli has stop woriking PHP Pthreads program

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, command-line-interface

I have a huge text file. I want to write specific lines from db to the file at specific places. I wrote a php script for this it ran for 17 days. To reduce the time I re-write the program using Php Pthreads as multi threaded program. Now I have divided the file into 100 small files. Now 100 threads are manipulating the files separately. The program runs fine for about a day but the command line gives CLI has stopped working error.

Here are the specifics:

> Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1
>   Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5
>   Ram: 4 GB
>   PHP Version: 5.5.12
>   Pthreads Version: 2.0.10

This is the windows log error:

> Log Name:      Application
>   Source:        Application Error
>   Date:          7/8/2015 7:41:22 AM
>   Event ID:      1000
>   Task Category: (100)
>   Level:         Error
>   Keywords:      Classic
>   User:          N/A
>   Computer:      ICT-DB-Migr
>   Description:
>   Faulting application name: php.exe, version: 5.5.12.0, time stamp: 0x53613fb5
>   Faulting module name: php5ts.dll, version: 5.5.12.0, time stamp: 0x53614545
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x000000000000ad68
>   Faulting process id: 0x10ec
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d0b889e4ff1462
>   Faulting application path: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php5ts.dll
>   Report Id: a05581e5-2516-11e5-9cc2-a0481c83537b

This is my php program:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

/**
 * Author: 
 * URL: 
 */

 $time_start = microtime(true); 

 class ThreadSafe extends Stackable {
   public function run(){}
 }


class WorkerThreads extends Thread
{
   private $workerId;
   private $conn;   

    public function __construct($id,$dataArray)
    {
    $this->workerId = $id;
    $this->dataArray2 = $dataArray;
    }

public function run()
{

    include "db_connect.php";


    $file_name="breaked_mark_files\USMARK_".$this->workerId.".mrk";     
    $file=fopen($file_name,"r") or exit("Unable to open file!");        
    $id=0;
    $dataCount=-1;
    $count852=0;
    $dataSubCount=0;

    while(!feof($file)){    

        echo 'worker '.$this->workerId." executing line record ".$id."    line number".$dataCount."".PHP_EOL;



        $line = fgets($file);   
        $field = substr($line,0,4);
        $strlenth = strlen($line);  
        $data = substr($line,6);    

        /* if($dataCount==1){   

            //var_dump($dataArray2);
            break;

        } */

        if($field == "=LDR"){       

            $count852=0;
            $dataCount++;   
            $dataSubCoun=0;                 
            $this->dataArray2[]=$line;

            $dataSubCount++;

        }elseif($field=="=852"){    

            if($count852 == 0){

                $array=explode("\$",$data);

                foreach($array as $key=>$value){

                    if($key !=0){

                        $str = $value;
                        $strlength=strlen($str);
                        $first_string=substr($str,0,1);

                        if($first_string == "p"){

                            $id=substr($str,1);                 

                        }           

                    }

                }

                $this->dataArray2[]=$line;
                //$count995++;
                $dataSubCount++;                    

            }else{      

                $this->dataArray2[]=$line;
                $dataSubCount++;
            }

        }else{

            $this->dataArray2[]=$line;
            $dataSubCount++;    

        }   

        //$id = intval($id);
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);            
        $sql = "SELECT languageData FROM data_table WHERE id='$id'";



        if($id != 0){               

            $result = $conn->query($sql);           

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $this->dataArray2[]=$row["languageData"];
                    $dataSubCount++;

                }                   

            } else {
                //echo "0 results of main record for id  ".$id."".PHP_EOL;
            }

            $sql = "SELECT holdingData FROM holding_data WHERE record_id='$id'";

            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                    $this->dataArray2[]=$row["holdingData"];
                    $dataSubCount++;

                }

                $id=0;                  

            } else {

                //echo "0 results of holding data for id ".$id."".PHP_EOL;
            }

        }   

    }

    $conn->close();
  }
}

// Worker pool
$workers = [];
$array=[];

foreach (range(0, 49) as $i){

$array[$i]= new ThreadSafe();   
}

// Initialize and start the threads

foreach (range(0, 49) as $i) {

  $workers[$i] = new WorkerThreads($i,$array[$i]);
  $workers[$i]->start();
}

// Let the threads come back
foreach (range(0, 49) as $i) {
$workers[$i]->join();
}



 $file=fopen("writtenFle.txt","w") or exit("Unable to open file!");

 $array_count = count($array);

 foreach(range(0, ($array_count-1)) as $i){

 $array_count2 = count($array[$i]);

 foreach(range(0, ($array_count2-1)) as $y){

    fwrite($file,$array[$i][$y]."\r\n"); 

  }

}

fclose($file);

$time_end = microtime(true);

$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;

echo 'Total Execution Time: '.$execution_time.' Mins'.PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Enabling [`log_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) might be useful.

Comment: Your CPU has at max. 8 logical processing cores. You shouldn't create more threads than that. If your application is I/O-limited, an event loop might be more beneficial. ([`stream_select()`](http://php.net/stream_select), [`Event`](http://php.net/Event))

Comment: Also, there a is a point of diminishing returns. At some point your threads hamper each others performance. I would not be surprised if that's already the case with 2 threads, provided your files all reside on the same device.